# How to recover missing files and folders after power loss on an encrypted LUKS drive

Tags: missing-data, data-recovery, luks

There was a power outage followed by flickering current at my place that damaged my motherboard, no more booting, black screen and fans turning. I took my on-board fully encrypted NVMe M.2 SSD out, put it in a USB adapter and plugged it into another PC. The drive seems fine i can boot on it and decrypt it but i have many missing folders crucial to me.
I searched for data recovery software compatible with LUKS to recover the missing files but i can't find one. Anyone has an idea on how i can recover these disappeared files?